# PHP passthru() function result?

Tags: php

How to get the result of passthru() function? That is its return true or false? I am developing a database backup program using passthru() function. Its run successfully but I want to display a message to user backup if successful or not. Following is my code - it ran and created a backup.sql file but displayed "Backup failed".

```
<?php
$filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y");
$cmd = "mysqldump -u root dudh_society >c:/Backup/$filename.sql";   
passthru( $cmd );
if(passthru($cmd) == true)
{
    echo "Backup Succesfully";
}
else
{
    echo "Backup failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: `passthru()` method return void [No value is returned]

Comment: Read Manual please http://ru2.php.net/passthru and try to use second function parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The signature of the function is:

   ```
   void passthru ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] )
   ```

   Which means, if you want to capture the exit status of the shell program, give it a second parameter:

   ```
   passthru($cmd, $status);

   if ($status == 0) {
       // success
   } else {
       // failure
   }
   ```
2. If you're going to `echo` anything else on that page, it's going to become part of the output. So the dumped MySQL file would contain "Backup Successful" at its end, which is probably not what you want at all. You'd have to redirect to another page and output the message there:

   ```
   header("Location: http://example.com/result.php?status=$status");
   ```

Comment: @Kamlesh  notice that `&$return_var` return `0` in case success and any non-zero number in case fails  Like Unix command
http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/41055-return-code-unix-command.html